# Remove if number of lines is less than two to the next newline value

Tags: batch-file, awk

I have a file similar to this:

> ```
> > DC
> A P C
> Q Z C
> D H C
> > DS
> J H S
> > DA
> U P A
> A E A
> U H A
> ```

I would like to delete parts if number of lines between two newline values (>) is less than e.g. 2. So the solution for my example would be:

> ```
> > DC
> A P C
> Q Z C
> D H C
> > DA
> U P A
> A E A
> U H A
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using `>` as the record separator:

```
gawk -v RS='>' -v nlines=2 '
    {sub(/\n$/,"");  n = split($0,a,/\n/)}
    n > nlines {print RS $0}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set here the number of lines
set num=2

set n=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a
   if "!line:~0,1!" equ ">" (
      if !n! gtr %num% for /L %%i in (1,1,!n!) do echo !line[%%i]!
      set n=0
   )
   set /A n+=1
   set "line[!n!]=%%a"
)
if !n! gtr %num% for /L %%i in (1,1,!n!) do echo !line[%%i]!
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, modify variable value `n=<of your interest>` according to your need, where `n` is minimum no of records between two `>`

One-liner:

```
awk -v n=2 'function pr(){if(i>=n)print s}/>/{pr();i=0;s=$0;next}{i++;s=s ORS $0}END{pr()}' infile
```

Better Readable:

```
awk -v n=2 '
            function pr(){
                 if(i>=n)print s; 
            }
            />/{
                 pr();
                 i = 0
                 s = $0
                 next
            }
            {
              i++;
              s = s ORS $0
            }
         END{
              pr()
            }
           ' infile
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
> DC
A P C
Q Z C
D H C
> DS
J H S
> DA
U P A
A E A
U H A
```

Output:

```
$ awk -v n=2 'function pr(){if(i>=n)print s}/>/{pr();i=0;s=$0;next}{i++;s=s ORS $0}END{pr()}' infile
> DC
A P C
Q Z C
D H C
> DA
U P A
A E A
U H A
```

Answer (score 0):

Another for GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"}/([^\n]*\n){3}/{printf RS $0}' file
> DC
A P C
Q Z C
D H C
> DA
U P A
A E A
U H A
```

(not thorougly tested, though.)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"\n" 'BEGIN{RS=">";ORS=">";} NF<=3 && NR>1{next;}1' file
```